# Angular material md-datepicker directive change layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

How can i change default styles of angular-material directive md-datepicker. Now i can move through the months with ther scroll but i want a datepicker like [this](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm-images/vue-material-datepicker/simple-version.png), with header and navigation arrows.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried yourself?

Comment: i use the most basic md-datepicker tag and the result is like this http://codepen.io/dplum128/pen/yakJVr. 
Is there another component to get the layout I need?

Comment: Theming can be done using, so that should take care of the different colors. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Not sure how to get the header and navigation arrows. Where did you see the example? Any way you can reverse engineer that code?